# Javascript regex check freezes web page

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a regex test on an email address input. This works fine for smaller strings but when the input string gets too long, the regex text just freezes the thread/web page.

The expression I am using is (Tried even the simplest ones with the same result):

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9ÆØÅÄÖæøåäö]+)([\._\-\+]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3\.[0-9]    {1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

The input is like this :

```
rjkfonsdjvcnkdcmklsdncjsdkcdsamcjbsdjcmsdcnsdjcvksadcnsdjbc
```

at the time of it breaking.

The Javascript code I use to validate :

```
function (regex, val) {
    var rx = new RegExp(regex);
    return rx.test(val);
}
```

Comment: make a fiddle and post it.

Comment: Your function validates this email: `test@testing.com]` http://regex101.com/r/rV7dN8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quantifying quantifiers, and that leads to catastrophic backtracking if a match can't be found. Especially a long input like that.

May I ask why you don't just do this?

```
<input type="email" />
```

Comment: Possibly due to it being a new HTML5 feature and while it does not break older browsers, it won't acutally force any kind of validation. On my project we use type="email" and for older browser we fall back to just checking if it's a string with an @ somewhere in the middle because as the OP just discovered, validating emails with a regexp is difficult, timeconsuming and will go wrong.

Comment: @niet-the-dark-absoul it's validation when it's on the serverside and good UX when it's on the client. If you can save the user a round-trip to the server when they mess up in an input-field that is good, but if the goal is security then yeah, put it on the server as well.

Comment: @ivarni I still don't see why we should worry about good UX when the user is deliberately using an outdated browser ;)